# Formsubmit.co activation email not received

Tags: forms, contact-form

The email address I am attempting to send to is one provided / hosted on 123-reg.

I received emails to that address if sent from my personal email, and I can also send emails back from within that inbox.

I have tested the contact form to make sure it works by first inputting my personal email address, and I receive the activation email as usual and once activated, can received contact sent via the contact form, directly to my personal email address.

However, when I use the email provided via 123reg, I don't receive the activation email at all. I've also checked spam folder, but nothing there either.

For anyone unfamiliar with formsubmit, here is the link: https://formsubmit.co/ -- what you see in the demo is pretty much all it takes to get a contact form set up. I've tried contacting them directly but it's been about a week or 2 and yet to receive a response.

If anyone can help, or suggest anything to help me figure out why it's not working it'd be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my knowledge, this is something you have to check with your email service provider. Because you have received FormSubmit emails into your personal email address, so the issue might be with the 123-reg.

Please try to contact them to get some support.

Answer (score 0):

This answer works. Remember to replace your email with the string sent in the activation email before you click on Activate.

```html
<form class="i-form" action="https://formsubmit.co/youremail@gmail.com" method="POST">
    <!--optional starts-->              <input type="hidden" name="_url" value="https://youremail@gmail.com/thepage.html"> <!--optional ends-->

                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="i-email">
                    <br>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="i-email" class="i-email">
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Get started">
                </form>
```

[Form activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdcFg.png)

[Form submitted by other user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b371X.png)

[User inputted submitted via form received in my inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9f95.png)

Comment: Thanks Atmas. This answer does indeed work - my specific issue/query was relating to whether I could do the same set up using an email address provided by 123-reg, as this was what wasn't working for me.